# How to get data in chunks from very large table which has primary key column data type as varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to retrieve data from table with 28 million rows. I want to retrieve 1 million rows at a time.

I have checked answers from following links
[Get data from large table in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952899/get-data-from-large-table-in-chunks)
[How can I get a specific chunk of results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439645/how-can-i-get-a-specific-chunk-of-results)
The solution suggests a query which has int ID column. In my case I have primary key column with varchar(15) as data type

I want to use something like this which is faster - 
    Select  top 2000 *
    from    t
    where ID >= @start_index
    order by ID

But since the ID column is varchar, I can not use integer index.

How can I efficiently get data in chunks from a table with primary key having varchar data type?

Comment: Redesign your data model.

Comment: Database is read only. I can not make any changes in database

Comment: Eventhough your ID is Varchar what kind of values exist in your Primary Key column. Either alphanumeric or numeric data

Comment: ID contains alphanumeric data and also contains characters like $ and _

Comment: You want to retrieve 1 million data among 28 million based on what criteria

Comment: There's no problem with ordering or useing `>=` but SQL Server 2012 provides the `[OFFSET and FETCH NEXT](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/using-new-offset-and-fetch-next-options) statements which make paging much easier. That said, a page of 2000 records is not a good idea.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe your *real* problem? The fastes way to export 1M rows is to read the data in a firehose fashion, eg with an SSIS package that exports it directly where it needs to go. Or use `bcp` to perform a bulk export operation. *Partitioning* the table can make processing faster if you only want to process the records in one partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your primary key has to be unique the same approach will work.  You can use >= with character columns.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest to use an offset ORDER BY like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY;
```

This way is very flexible.